# How to get access for Progress bar in Asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, progress-bar

I have this code :

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Progress Bar With Label</h2>
  <div  class="progress">
    <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="70" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:70%">
      70%
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

this will be show a Progress bar with text 70% ,  the question is how to get access of this progress bar in cs code and make change of percentage and other?

Comment: Did you try sending percentage via ViewData or Model? Does it need to change dynamically?

Comment: It's a client side thing. You can't really update it from the server very easily. What are you trying to show the progress of, exactly?

Comment: I try to show a Tasks completing progress , in code I want to change the percentage. @ADyson

Comment: Yes obviously you want to record the progress of a task. What is the task though, exactly? That's what I meant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access progress bar in cs (code behind) file by assigning the attribute `runat="server"` and `id="progressBar"`.

Following is the complete working code so you can try this.

Default.aspx:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Progress Bar With Label</h2>
  <div  class="progress">
    <div runat="server" id="progressBar" class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" >
        <p id="lblPercentage" runat="server"></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Default.aspx.cs

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        progressBar.Attributes.Add("style", "width:50%");
        progressBar.Attributes.Add("aria-valuenow", "50");
        lblPercentage.InnerText = "50%";
    }
```

Comment: Not going to be updatable in real time though is it, if you have to post back to the server every time... Your answer is technically correct I think, but not especially practical